# How to build libgpio.a from a makefile that builds libgpio.so

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, raspbian

I need to build this static library using the makefile, but there is no existing option to build a `libgpio.a` file

I was able to build it, but for some reason I am getting undefined reference errors when I include it in my project

```
Error       undefined reference to `cmdInfo'        
Error       undefined reference to `cmdParse'       
Error       undefined reference to `cmdParseScript' 
Error       undefined reference to `cmdUsage'
```

Which are structs defined in `commands.h` file

I added a line to the makefile

`pigpio.a: pigpio.c pigpio.h command.c command.h custom.cext
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c -o libpigpio.a pigpio.o pigpio.c`

I built it with

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/PIGPIO $ make pigpio.a
gcc -O3 -Wall -pthread -fpic -c -o libpigpio.a pigpio.o pigpio.c
gcc: warning: pigpio.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

I am confident its something I typed incorrectly into the Makefile, since I am getting the `linker input file unused because linking not done` warning

Please help me correct this, thank you,

Entire makefile below

```
    #
# Set CROSS_PREFIX to prepend to all compiler tools at once for easier
# cross-compilation.
CROSS_PREFIX =
CC           = $(CROSS_PREFIX)gcc
AR           = $(CROSS_PREFIX)ar
RANLIB       = $(CROSS_PREFIX)ranlib
SIZE         = $(CROSS_PREFIX)size
STRIP        = $(CROSS_PREFIX)strip
SHLIB        = $(CC) -shared
STRIPLIB     = $(STRIP) --strip-unneeded

SOVERSION    = 1

CFLAGS  += -O3 -Wall -pthread

LIB1     = libpigpio.so
OBJ1     = pigpio.o command.o

LIB2     = libpigpiod_if.so
OBJ2     = pigpiod_if.o command.o

LIB3     = libpigpiod_if2.so
OBJ3     = pigpiod_if2.o command.o

LIB      = $(LIB1) $(LIB2) $(LIB3)

ALL     = $(LIB) x_pigpio x_pigpiod_if x_pigpiod_if2 pig2vcd pigpiod pigs

LL1      = -L. -lpigpio -pthread -lrt

LL2      = -L. -lpigpiod_if -pthread -lrt

LL3      = -L. -lpigpiod_if2 -pthread -lrt

prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = $(prefix)
bindir = $(exec_prefix)/bin
includedir = $(prefix)/include
libdir = $(prefix)/lib
mandir = $(prefix)/man

all:    $(ALL)

lib:    $(LIB)

pigpio.o: pigpio.c pigpio.h command.h custom.cext
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c -o pigpio.o pigpio.c

pigpio.a: pigpio.c pigpio.h command.c command.h custom.cext
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c -o libpigpio.a pigpio.o pigpio.c

pigpiod_if.o: pigpiod_if.c pigpio.h command.h pigpiod_if.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c -o pigpiod_if.o pigpiod_if.c

pigpiod_if2.o: pigpiod_if2.c pigpio.h command.h pigpiod_if2.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c -o pigpiod_if2.o pigpiod_if2.c

command.o: command.c pigpio.h command.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c -o command.o command.c

x_pigpio:   x_pigpio.o $(LIB1)
    $(CC) -o x_pigpio x_pigpio.o $(LL1)

x_pigpiod_if:   x_pigpiod_if.o $(LIB2)
    $(CC) -o x_pigpiod_if x_pigpiod_if.o $(LL2)

x_pigpiod_if2:  x_pigpiod_if2.o $(LIB3)
    $(CC) -o x_pigpiod_if2 x_pigpiod_if2.o $(LL3)

pigpiod:    pigpiod.o $(LIB1)
    $(CC) -o pigpiod pigpiod.o $(LL1)
    $(STRIP) pigpiod

pigs:       pigs.o command.o
    $(CC) -o pigs pigs.o command.o
    $(STRIP) pigs

pig2vcd:    pig2vcd.o
    $(CC) -o pig2vcd pig2vcd.o
    $(STRIP) pig2vcd

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.i *.s *~ $(ALL) *.so.$(SOVERSION)

ifeq ($(DESTDIR),)
  PYINSTALLARGS =
else
  PYINSTALLARGS = --root=$(DESTDIR)
endif

install:    $(ALL)
    install -m 0755 -d                             $(DESTDIR)/opt/pigpio/cgi
    install -m 0755 -d                             $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)
    install -m 0644 pigpio.h                       $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)
    install -m 0644 pigpiod_if.h                   $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)
    install -m 0644 pigpiod_if2.h                  $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)
    install -m 0755 -d                             $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
    install -m 0755 libpigpio.so.$(SOVERSION)      $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
    install -m 0755 libpigpiod_if.so.$(SOVERSION)  $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
    install -m 0755 libpigpiod_if2.so.$(SOVERSION) $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(libdir) && ln -fs libpigpio.so.$(SOVERSION)      libpigpio.so
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(libdir) && ln -fs libpigpiod_if.so.$(SOVERSION)  libpigpiod_if.so
    cd $(DESTDIR)$(libdir) && ln -fs libpigpiod_if2.so.$(SOVERSION) libpigpiod_if2.so
    install -m 0755 -d                             $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    install -m 0755 pig2vcd                        $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    install -m 0755 pigpiod                        $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    install -m 0755 pigs                           $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    if which python2; then python2 setup.py install $(PYINSTALLARGS); fi
    if which python3; then python3 setup.py install $(PYINSTALLARGS); fi
    install -m 0755 -d                             $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/man1
    install -m 0644 p*.1                           $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/man1
    install -m 0755 -d                             $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/man3
    install -m 0644 p*.3                           $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/man3
ifeq ($(DESTDIR),)
    ldconfig
endif

uninstall:
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/pigpio.h
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/pigpiod_if.h
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/pigpiod_if2.h
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libpigpio.so
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libpigpiod_if.so
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libpigpiod_if2.so
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libpigpio.so.$(SOVERSION)
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libpigpiod_if.so.$(SOVERSION)
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/libpigpiod_if2.so.$(SOVERSION)
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/pig2vcd
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/pigpiod
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/pigs
    if which python2; then python2 setup.py install $(PYINSTALLARGS) --record /tmp/pigpio >/dev/null; sed 's!^!$(DESTDIR)!' < /tmp/pigpio | xargs rm -f >/dev/null; fi
    if which python3; then python3 setup.py install $(PYINSTALLARGS) --record /tmp/pigpio >/dev/null; sed 's!^!$(DESTDIR)!' < /tmp/pigpio | xargs rm -f >/dev/null; fi
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/man1/pig*.1
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/man1/libpigpio*.1
    rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/man3/pig*.3
ifeq ($(DESTDIR),)
    ldconfig
endif

$(LIB1):    $(OBJ1)
    $(SHLIB) -pthread -Wl,-soname,$(LIB1).$(SOVERSION) -o $(LIB1).$(SOVERSION) $(OBJ1)
    ln -fs $(LIB1).$(SOVERSION) $(LIB1)
    $(STRIPLIB) $(LIB1)
    $(SIZE)     $(LIB1)

$(LIB2):    $(OBJ2)
    $(SHLIB) -pthread -Wl,-soname,$(LIB2).$(SOVERSION) -o $(LIB2).$(SOVERSION) $(OBJ2)
    ln -fs $(LIB2).$(SOVERSION) $(LIB2)
    $(STRIPLIB) $(LIB2)
    $(SIZE)     $(LIB2)

$(LIB3):    $(OBJ3)
    $(SHLIB) -pthread -Wl,-soname,$(LIB3).$(SOVERSION) -o $(LIB3).$(SOVERSION) $(OBJ3)
    ln -fs $(LIB3).$(SOVERSION) $(LIB3)
    $(STRIPLIB) $(LIB3)
    $(SIZE)     $(LIB3)

# generated using gcc -MM *.c

pig2vcd.o: pig2vcd.c pigpio.h
pigpiod.o: pigpiod.c pigpio.h
pigs.o: pigs.c pigpio.h command.h pigs.h
x_pigpio.o: x_pigpio.c pigpio.h
x_pigpiod_if.o: x_pigpiod_if.c pigpiod_if.h pigpio.h
x_pigpiod_if2.o: x_pigpiod_if2.c pigpiod_if2.h pigpio.h
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late but I had the exact same situation and was finally able to solve it:

Basically you need to call `ar` to create the `libpigpio.a` library from `pigpio.o` and `command.o`, then link with `-lrt` and `-lpthread`.

I ended up with adding the following lines/target to the Makefile:

```
LIB4     = libpigpio.a
OBJ4     = pigpio.o command.o

LIB      = $(LIB1) $(LIB2) $(LIB3) $(LIB4)

# ...

$(LIB4):        $(OBJ4)
        $(AR) crs $(LIB4) $(OBJ4)
```

Then in my project I use these linker flags:

```
-L /path/to/pigpio -static -lpigpio -lpthread -lrt
```

and it works.